# Capturing a processes file activity and transmitting it to a remote host in real time

Tags: filesystems, remote, file-transfer, real-time

Are there any tools out there to intercept all the file activity of a process, transmit that to a process on a remote host (eg. zmq), and replay it there, in real time?

This is to enable remote processes that don't have access to the file system of the server process to read and write files, but "across the wire", as it were.

Performance, of course, is a concern, as this won't scale well unless perhaps it's kernel-level and backed by a cache of sorts, but this has become more an academic doodle for me right now. So even if it's a user-space thing, I might be able to satisfy my curiosity.

I see some interesting things like ReplayFS - https://www.filesystems.org/docs/replayfs/index.html - but not real-time etc

Comment: *as this won't scale well unless perhaps it's kernel-level and backed by a cache of sorts*  Something like NFS...

Comment: Like a user-space NFS, or VFS, right.